# Issue with constraints set programmatically

Tags: swift, constraints, swift2

I have been struggling with this all day now - I need to add a view as a rightBarButtonItems in my navigation bar, containing a UILabel and an UIImageView.. Because of that, I need to create the view programmatically, set the constraints programmatically and add the view as the rightBarButtonItems.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

.

.

And this is what I get:

[image]

It seems that no matter what I do, I cant move the down-arrow.. It needs to be on the right side of the label, and aligned with the centerY.

This is my code:

```
    //Elements
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 30)
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let codedLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    codedLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30)
    codedLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    codedLabel.text = "FILTRER"
    codedLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    codedLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    codedLabel.font = UIFont(name: Constants.ubuntuBold, size: 18.0)!
    codedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    codedLabel.sizeToFit()

    let codedImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    codedImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 5.7)
    codedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "dragToRefreshArrow")
    codedImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

    containerView.addSubview(codedLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(codedImageView)

    containerView.sizeToFit()

    //Constraints
   containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Label
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedLabel, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedLabel, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true

    //ImageView
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedImageView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: codedLabel, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedImageView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedImageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: codedLabel, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true

    let item = UIBarButtonItem()
    item.customView = containerView

    var negativeSpace:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpace.width = -10.0

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [negativeSpace, item]
```

Anyone has an idea about what I'm doing wrong? :-)

Comment: Yes, *all* views using programmatic autolayout must have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`

Comment: @BallpointBen- this might have been the problem :) Now I'm able to move the arrow at least! Thanks man! I'll post the final solution when I get it working properly :))

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the constraint to the view. Something like:

```
let myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(....)
myConstraint.active = ture
self.containerView.addConstraints(myConstraint)
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what this should help :)? Can you explain a little further? It just seems like the very first constraint I already have added?

Comment: @NicolaiHarbo dude your not adding the constraints to anything. What I'm trying to say is set the constraint to a var and then add that var to a view.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the arrow (codedImageView) on the right side of the label (codedLabel), aligned CenterY and inside de container (ContainerView), you need the following constraints:

- codedImageView.leading = codedLabel.trailing => this will move the codedImageView right of codedLabel
- codedImageView.centerY = codedLabel.centerY => this will vertical center it
- codedImageView.trailing = containerView.trailing => This will set it at the end and within the containerView.

This generated the following constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedImageView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: codedLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedImageView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: codedImageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: codedLabel, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
```

See how the first and third constraint are different? In your example you attached it to the top left corner of the codedLabel instead of center right.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I just tried your code, but the arrow is still stuck in the left top corner.. It's like I cant move it at all.. I'm not sure it it's because the containerview doesn't have any constraints around it, as It's in the navigationbar.. Could be?